# DBSCAN vs self implemented clustering function

Tags: postgis, clustering

In your experience, would a minimal code (because I am not very experienced with PostGIS)- self implemented clustering function be more accurate (and fast) than DBSCAN? For some reason DBSCAN is not giving accurate results. It is a few hundred meters off.

Comment: If you can write faster and more accurate function, why not to make a pull request and enhance https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html?

Comment: Have you looked at st_clusterwithin and st_clusterkmeans?  Are you sure that st_clusterdbscan is the appropriate clustering method for your problem?  In my experience - you're probably not going to be able to write a better clustering function that what already exists.  If you can, you should definitely make a pull request and add it as an enhancement to postgis.  You might be better off exploring all the existing clustering methods and if none of them work, then think about creating your own function.